# Tires squealing when braking

Tags: tires, alignment

When I apply the brakes at high speeds, not lightly but not enough for them to lock up, my tires squeal.
I believe the sound is coming from the tires and not the brakes at all.
One thing to note is the tires age is almost over and should be changed soon. Could worn out tires cause that squealing? Also I just did an alignment job on my car but I don't particularly remember it being apparent by the the alignment job directly after. Also my tires have been squealing when taking turns with the steering wheel fully locked at speed not sure if related but has been doing that for a long time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, tire squealing under high brake loads is usually worn out tires, but may also have something to do with the tire compound, tire inflation and road temperature.